# Set positions in a list, keeping tied places then incrementing back to the positions

Tags: python

I have a list of objects which have points and I'm looping through this list to assign the object's position in the list.

If the points are tied between multiple objects they share the same position value, but then the next object with a different point value should be assigned the place as the overall ordering, not `tied_value + 1`.

For example, tied positions would look like:

- 1
- 2
- 2
- 4
- 5

My current solution is:

```
by_points = sorted(
    objs,
    key=lambda s: getattr(s, point_field, 0),
    reverse=True
)

# Assign the position of 1 to the first object.
position = 1
setattr(by_points[0], position_field, position)

if len(by_points) > 1:
    tied_position = 0
    for i in range(1, len(by_points)):
        previous_points = getattr(by_points[i-1], point_field, 0)
        current_points = getattr(by_points[i], point_field, 0)

        if previous_points != current_points:
            # We know objects are in the order of increasing points.
            position += 1
            if tied_position:
                position += tied_position
            # reset the tie
            tied_position = 0
        else:
            # Position tied, start a count so we know where the position needs to be after the tie is over
            tied_position += 1

        setattr(by_points[i], position_field, position)
```

I've verified the results are correct, but is there a better approach?

Comment: @Raystafarian I wrote this rather late in the day. Just thought, pasting the values into excel alongside an incremental index verifies it. The data is good, and looks correct.